# AM Demodulation MC1496

Tags: analog, communication

I am trying to analyze the demodulator product detector circuit. This is done by the IC called MC1496, I find its datasheet, this circuit is in page 10 and the link is : https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC1496-D.PDF

But I got stacked in some components. I do not understand what is the function of the pink circled capacitor. Can someone help me for this by explaining in electronical way? I took analog electronics and communication theory course, but I did not take a communication electronics course so I'm pretty new on this. I know what product detector do, what should be the output, what are the amplitudes of carrier and message signal but it is just on a paper and they are all about calculations. This is the first time that I go that deep. Thanks in advance. :) Here is the circuit diagram and inside of IC.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You already asked essentially this same question; the rule here is that you do not delete and re-post, but rather use *edits* to fix your existing question.  Worse, you've now removed the link to the PDF which at least should have gotten you started in understanding the earlier version of your posting.

Comment: What do you notice about pin 6 vs pin 12 on all of the circuits on page 10?

Comment: The pink cap makes the carrier reject with a 2nd order LPF with the blue cap

Comment: The net effect is -3dB ~6kHz LPF with -40dB @ 170kHz

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 Finally someone gives meaningful answer without saying "Read the datasheet". Thanks so much. Anyway, this pink capacitor is related with the resistor which is connected to 12 V right sir?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I changed my source, I decided to look it from the datasheet. What is the problem? This circuit is more understandable than the previous circuit. I am doing what you say, reading the datasheet and sir, you keep on giving minus repetititons to me I can't understand your attitude towards me. I am trying to learn something...

Comment: @gok2 the problem here (as I see it) and in your now deleted question is that you just were not reading what was in front of your eyes. The original circuit clearly showed a demodulator because that is what was said on the diagram yet you were calling it a modulation circuit. In other words, you were just not doing the basics and getting to grips with things. You were also insisting that the circuit you had shown was not in the data sheet. You were advised to read the data sheet and eventually you got there.....

Comment: ....You appeared to be sarcastic with me in your deleted question and you have not been very receptive here. This makes folk not want to help you. All along, the answer was in the data sheet and eventually you are starting to realize this. However, this site is not geared up to take someone by the hand and do a full tear-down and learning exercise on a particular subject especially when your apparent starting point was so distant that you couldn't match up "modulation" and "demodulation" in your deleted question and still not match it up properly in this question.

Comment: @Andyaka sir my words is not for you, you know electronic circuits are like geometry, If you don't see it you don't see it. Sometimes really easy diagrams could not be understood like my situation.In the previous circuit, I did not see that there is a low pass filter, I changed my circuit with respect to the datasheet and I now see there is a filter. The deleted question is different type of this circuit, there are potentiometers etc. By the way, I am reading what was in front of my eyes. There are no explanations about this capacitor. It is not that hard to say that there is a filter or etc..

Comment: To take just one example : now you've posted the information you should have three questions ago : pins 2 and 3 are labelled "Gain Adjust". Is it really so difficult to conclude from that, R6 sets the conversion gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I took analog electronics and communication theory course*

You should then be somewhat familiar with the process used to modulate and demodulate a signal using multiplication; the MC1496 is a very old 4 quadrant multiplier; it multiplies two signals using analogue methods.

So, when you multiply an SSB signal (call it A) with it's original carrier frequency (call it B) you get the sum and the difference frequencies. In other words (using [this formula sheet](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/%7Ebernd/F12MR2/mformula.pdf)) we get this: -

$$\sin A \cdot\sin B = \dfrac{\cos(A − B) − \cos(A + B)}{2}$$

That is what the MC1496 is doing but, nobody is interested in \$\cos(A+B)\$ because that isn't the demodulated signal we are looking for. When demodulating SSB we are interested in \$\cos(A-B)\$ i.e. the difference frequency because that is the demodulated baseband signal we want. We don't want \$\cos(A+B)\$ and we filter it away.

> *I do not understand what is the function of the pink circled
> capacitor.*

That capacitor and the 3.0 k resistor above it apply a 1st order low pass filter. The 1 kΩ resistor to its right and the next 0.005 μF capacitor add a second stage of filtering to eradicate the unwanted high frequency content a bit more.

Comment: if he understood what "4 quadrant multiplier" really means, he wouldn't be asking what does C pink do, would he?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 my very first line explains it: *The MC1496 is a very old 4 quadrant multiplier; it multiplies two signals using analogue methods.*

Comment: ok that explains R1C1 thanks andy

Comment: great explanation sir, I am just confused about that the one of the low pass filter, which is blue circled, is directly connected between pin 12 and ground but the other one that you said with 3k resistor above is connected to pin 12 and a 12 V DC source. Actually I have doubt there, I mean why we connect it to 12 V ?

Comment: Pin 12 is an open collector output hence it needs a resistor (3.0 k) up to 12 volts. But, given that a BJT's collector acts like a current source, the impedance at pin 12 is defined by the 3.0 k resistor hence, pin 12 acts like a voltage source feeding through a 3.0 k resistor (as per [Thevenin's equivalent circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem)) and the 3.0 k resistor forms the resistive element in a low pass RC filter.

Answer (score 1):

This (pink-circled) capacitor function (C1 here) needs you to learn some fundamentals (on your own) ;

- collector output **current-source equivalent** *converted* to a voltage source in series with Rc, then **superposition** adding next impedance stages.
- This mixer is a **differential output** with one side shunted to double the output here. ( see orig. schematic , not shown here)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffiBCu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: so much thanks sir